# Potential Divider Circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

Consider the following circuit:

[image]

From my understanding, consider the series circuit without the $V_o$ part. The voltage must be used between resistors $R_1$and $R_2$. We know $V=IR$ from ohms law. As the current through each resistor is the same, the voltage across the respective resitances is dependent on there resistances. Hence the voltage across $R_1$is $\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}V_I$.

Now when we add a circuit across $R_1$, the voltage $V_o$ is the same as the voltage across $R_1$ as voltages are the same within a parallel circuit. This makes sense.

However, what is unclear to me here, is what happens to the current. How do you calculate what current flows through the $V_o$ part of the circuit? Theoretically if the $V_o$ part had little resistance, couldn't the current bypass going through the resistance $R_1$? Now if this was the case, then the voltage across $R_1$ would be extremely small. So it seems $V_o$ is actually dependent on the resistance of this part of the circuit. What is going wrong here?

Now consider this circuit

[image]

Consider the middle wire between $V_o1$ and $V_o2$. Theoretically, shouldn't all current flow through this, as it has no resistance? Hence current shouldn't be able to enter the $V_o1$ part of this circuit.

Whats happening to current in these circuits? This is making me extremely confused. How can you calculate what current is going through $V_o$? Is it complicated or trivial?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Is there current flowing through the middle wire in the above circuit? I suspect there isn't. However, could someone explain this?

Comment: In _practice,_ and speaking as an almost-EE (I used to sit at a desk next to the EEs at work) if the "load" on the voltage divider is much smaller than the current through R1, and if the voltage is not critical,  then we just pretend that the load is zero. Otherwise, we cannot treat the divider and the load as separate circuits. We have to analyze the system as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you calculate what current flows through the $V_o$ part of the circuit?

The output current must be 0, otherwise your assumption that "the current through each resistor is the same" is no longer valid.

> So it seems $V_o$ is actually dependent on the resistance of this part of the circuit. What is going wrong here?

Nothing wrong. Just that the resistor divider formula you cited is not valid in this situation. It's only valid when the output current is 0 or negligible.

You could use other circuit analysis techniques, like node or mesh analysis to find the currents in all the branches (R1, R2, and the newly introduced load) if the load current were non-zero.

> Consider the middle wire between $V_o1$ and $V_o2$. Theoretically, shouldn't all current flow through this, as it has no resistance?

It does, because the wire leading off to the right isn't connected to anything, so there's nowhere for current that flows off that way to go.

If there was some load off the the right, then current might flow there. The wires connecting to that load have no resistance, the same as the one connecting R1 to R2, so the current flowing to the right would depend on the load connected there, not on the ideal wires that connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the confusion is here.  In a series circuit, such as this, the current is the same in all components of the circuit. Conversely, in a parallel connected circuit,  the voltage is the same across all components.  The measurement of voltage is assumed to be ideal i.e. it presents an infinite resistance and draws no current. Indeed modern voltmeters have fet input stages that have input resistances of several Megohms.  Conversely an ideal ammeter has zero ohms resistance.